# How does MySQL handle storing ENUM value that doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, enums

For example suppose my ENUM is "a", "b", "c" and I try to store "d" how is MySQL supposed to behave?  Also from a design perspective is there a correct way of handling this case? (your program receives "d" fo the above enum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using strict mode then an error will occur otherwise it will store an empty string with a value of zero.

The correct way to handle this case would be to ensure invalid values never get inserted or use another data type.